# PHP sorted Array is not sorted in JS after json_encode

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, sorting

I have two arrays in PHP. I sort the first array like this:

```
arsort($array1);
```

And then output the arrays like that:

```
foreach ($array1 as $key => $val) {
    $output .= "<tr>
    <td>".$array1[$key]."</td>
    <td>".$array2[$key]."</td>
    </tr>";
}
print($output);
```

Here is what the Arrays look like:

```
$array1 = [21, 12, 64, 87, 5, 823, ...]
$array2 = ["label1", "label2", "label3", "label4", ...]
```

Every element in `$array2` is associated with an element in `$array1` so in this example the element "label1" should be linked to the element 21 (both key 0) but if I sort `$array1` and the element keys change they should also change in `$array2`

I also need to use `$array2` in Javascript with the same order so I use json_encode like that:

```
$arr2 = json_encode($array2);

$somejs = <<<ECHO
<script type="text/javascript">

var arr2 = $arr2;
for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    console.log(arr2[i]);
}
</script>
ECHO;
echo $somejs;
```

But it doesn't get displayed like in the foreach loop but in its original order (keys: 0, 1, 2, 3, ...)

Is it somehow possible to pass the keys to the created Javascript Array or do you guys have another, maybe better solution?

Hope my question is clear tell me if there is a problem :)

Thanks

Comment: You have not sorted `$array2`, so sort `$array2` or output `$array1`

Comment: I cant sort `$array2` because its order depends on the order of `$array1`. will edit this in my original post

Comment: What do these arrays look like, add a `print_r()` sample of `$array1` and `$array2`

Comment: Make a new array `$array3` that contains the elements of `$array2` ordered by `$array1`.

Comment: Your question is still unclear about the relationship between `$array1` and `$array2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make an array `$array3` that contains the reordered version of `$array2`. You can do this while you're print the table.

```
$array3 = array();
foreach ($array1 as $key => $val) {
    $output .= "<tr>
    <td>".$array1[$key]."</td>
    <td>".$array2[$key]."</td>
    </tr>";
    $array3[] = $array2[$key];
}
print($output);
```

Then use `json_encode($array3)` when you create the Javascript.

Comment: This works fine thank you. Just thought about a simpler solution because my code gets more and more messy :S
Will edit my original post for the relationship between the arrays

Comment: Oh mine looks a bit similiar, I may as well delete mine.

Comment: @Mugen I figured out the relationship when I looked closer at the `foreach` loop.

Comment: @Mugen Another solution would be to put `json_encode($array1)` in the Javascript, and then have JS access `arr2[arr1[i]]`